# Use of more than 1 reactive parameter in wired method

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, custom, ui-api

I am trying to create a reusable component to fetch picklist values of a specific field dynamically on a record page.

The field API name can be configured in the record page.

**Updated**

I am trying to follow this approach to fetch picklist values based on record type id.

**Step 1**: wired method to fetch current record details and filter out record type id, selected value of configured picklist and object API name.

**Step 2** : Another wired method will use the record type id and picklist field api dynamically to fetch list of picklist values.

Using those two wired method, I am trying to design a reusable progress bar component.

Here is my entire js code:

```
@api progressFieldAPIName;
@api recordId;

selectedVal = '';
recordTypeId = '';
objectApiName = '';
dynamicfieldapiname = '';

@wire(getRecord, { 
    recordId : '$recordId',
    layoutTypes : 'Full' //fields: [STAGE_NAME]
})
wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('data>>>'+JSON.stringify(data));
        this.objectApiName = data.apiName;
        var picklistvar = data.fields[this.progressFieldAPIName];
        
        this.dynamicfieldapiname = this.progressFieldAPIName;
        this.recordTypeId = data.recordTypeId;

        this.selectedVal = picklistvar.displayValue;
    }
    else{
        console.log('getRecord error>>'+JSON.stringify(error));
    }    
}  

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId', fieldApiName: '$progressFieldAPIName' })
picklistvals({ error, data }) {
}
```

I am getting this error message from getPicklistvalues wired method : **{"status":400,"body":{"message":"Parameter required: fieldApiName","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"MISSING_ARGUMENT"}**

even though the `progressFieldAPIName` is configured in the page where I am using the component.

Is it not allowed to have more than 1 reactive parameter in wired call?

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you share more of your code, including where you define `progressFieldAPIName`?

Comment: Why is there an `@` in front of the `progressFieldAPIName` property declaration?

Comment: Also, please provide the exact error message, making sure to [edit] your question to add the details.

Comment: Sorry. It was a silly mistake. I am updating my post with entire code.

Comment: - You need to make sure that the **progressFieldAPIName** property has the **@api** decorator and that it has a valid value when the component is rendered. You can use the `connectedCallback` or `renderedCallback` lifecycle hooks to check or assign the value of the **progressFieldAPIName** property.
- You need to make sure that the progressFieldAPIName property is a string that represents the API name of the picklist field, such as 'StageName'. You also need to make sure that the progressFieldAPIName property is reactive, meaning that it has a $ prefix in the wire adapter configuration.

Comment: Hello @TusharJadav, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have marked the progressFieldAPIName as string in targetConfig and tried with reactive property as you can see in my code. I have also tried the connectedCallback but the only problem is my 2nd wired method depends on first one. Without the result of first method, the 2nd one can't be executed. That's why I am setting up the input variables of 2nd method inside 1st method.

Comment: In the first wire method, you have assigned the **progressFieldAPIName** to the **dynamicfieldapiname** variable. Is the **dynamicfieldapiname** variable is `@track` decorator? If yes then can you try to pass this variable into the second wire method? like this: `@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId', fieldApiName: '$dynamicfieldapiname' })
picklistvals({ error, data }) {
}`

Comment: hi @TusharJadav, Both the variables by default reactive after Spring'20 release. Both of them are assigned with the field API name, progressFieldAPIName  from page configuration and dynamicfieldapiname from getRecord callback. But none of these approaches are working even if console.log showing valid value of both the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for spending time on this post.
After doing some more debug, I am able to find out the root cause.

I was simply passing the field api name without appending object name before it.

For example, If i need to fetch StageName picklist value, I was simply providing the value of progressFieldAPIName as StageName which is wrong.

I need to pass the field api name in this format : objectapiname + '.' + progressFieldAPIName i.e. **Opportuity.StageName**

Answer (score 0):

`@progressFieldAPIName` is being interpreted as a decorator, so what's expected afterwards is a parameter/argument list.  I think you meant to write:

```
@api progressFieldAPIName;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.